# Установка java 1.8.0 на Kali Linux virtualbox

Tags: kali-linux

Говорю сразу. нужна именно эта версия.
Задаю вопрос, после нескольких блужданий в интернете.
Перепробовал все. Замену с помощью Waw, удалением и прочим.
Знатоки, помогите подробным советом. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score 3):

Проверяем версию:

```
java --version
```

Результат:

```
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=on -Dswing.aatext=true
openjdk 11.0.12 2021-07-20
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.12+7-post-Debian-2)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.12+7-post-Debian-2, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Вводим:

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk
```

Результат:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package openjdk-8-jdk
```

Переходим на сайт https://jdk.java.net/java-se-ri/8-MR3 и качаем Oracle Linux 7.6 x64 Java Development Kit (md5) 167 MB. Распаковываем в `/usr/lib/jvm/` и переименовываем папку в `java-8`.

Вводим:

```
update-alternatives --list java
```

Результат:

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java
```

Поочередно в терминал вводим команды:

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java /usr/lib/jvm/java-8/bin/java 1
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/javac javac /usr/lib/jvm/java-8/bin/javac 1
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/jar jar /usr/lib/jvm/java-8/bin/jar 1
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/jshell jshell /usr/lib/jvm/java-8/bin/jshell 1
```

Получаем:

```
update-alternatives: error: alternative path /usr/lib/jvm/java-8/bin/jshell doesn't exist
```

Теперь вводим:

```
update-alternatives --display java
```

Вывод:

```
java - auto mode
  link best version is /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java
  link currently points to /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java
  link java is /usr/bin/java
  slave java.1.gz is /usr/share/man/man1/java.1.gz
/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java - priority 1111
  slave java.1.gz: /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/man/man1/java.1.gz
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8/bin/java - priority 1
```

Следующая команда:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

Вывод терминала:

```
There are 2 choices for the alternative java (providing /usr/bin/java).

  Selection    Path                                         Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
* 0            /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java   1111      auto mode
  1            /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java   1111      manual mode
  2            /usr/lib/jvm/java-8/bin/java                  1         manual mode

Press <enter> to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number:
```

Вводим цифру **2** и нажимаем `Enter`

Терминал:

```
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-8/bin/java to provide /usr/bin/java (java) in manual mode
```

Командой `sudo update-alternatives --config java` проверяем, что теперь выбрана нужная версия `java`:

```
There are 2 choices for the alternative java (providing /usr/bin/java).

  Selection    Path                                         Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java   1111      auto mode
  1            /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java   1111      manual mode
* 2            /usr/lib/jvm/java-8/bin/java                  1         manual mode

Press <enter> to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number:
```

Нажимаем `Ctrl + C` и выходим.

Проверяем версию `java`:

```
java -version
```

Получаем вывод:

```
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=on -Dswing.aatext=true
openjdk version "1.8.0_41"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_41-b04)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.40-b25, mixed mode)
```

Необходимая версия установлена.

Comment: молодцы, хороший ответ!